# loading the bulk data from s3 to redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am using sql workbench/j copy command to copy data from s3 to redshift ,but i need to process the many copy command , how can i make a script and process all the commands at once ,is there any other way than sql workbench/j where we can process script through cli ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the 'psql' command line tool to do this. Details on this can be found in the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-from-psql.html).